# bundle modules into one "namespace"

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I am new to angular2 and system js.

when i use

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
```

at the top of my typescript class I know that 'angular2/core' actually refers to a number of different classes.

I want to know how to set this up in my own system.js environment.

for example if I have a folder in my app folder called model which contains a separate class for each "object" in my project:

app/model/user.ts
app/model/object1.ts
app/model/object2.ts
app/model/object3.ts

right now in order to use these classes in other parts of my app I have to import each file separately at the top of my ts class

```
import {User} from '../../model/user';
import {object1} from '../../model/object1';
import {object2} from '../../model/object2';
import {object3} from '../../model/object3';
```

How can I change it so that I can import like this:

```
import {User, object1, object2, object3} from '../../model/';
```

here is mt current system.js set up:

```
System.config({
    map: { 'app': './Modules/Shifts/app' },
    packages: {
        //sets the root path of the Angular2 App
        'Modules/Shifts/app': {               
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }        
});
System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

How do I set this up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution would be to create a helper file that re-exports necessary classes.

What you need to do is to create a file called `../../model.ts` with the content:

```
export {User} from './model/user'
export {object1} from './model/object1'
// ...
```

Now you can rewrite your imports as

```
import {User, object1, object2, object3} from '../../model';
```

Or you could also use `../../model/index.ts` with adjusted paths `export {User} from './user'`.